# Jquery combobox strange behavior when optimizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I am trying to optimize the [combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) code because I have some latency in my project due to the fact that I create four input boxes in a row. I have some improvement using `appendChild()` instead of `insertAfter()` in this [**jFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mHQcW/5/). But I get strange behavior when I click in the dropdown arrow on the right of each input field.

**Question:** Why is that happening? or What exactly is happening? Can someone point out how to solve this issue?

Update#1: My explanation and question implie that I have already tried the **original code** and as is **slow** I want to **optimize** it!

Update#2: After a short profiling with Chrome Developer Tools I think I **may** have resolved this issue. Although the original question is still on.

I took three tests:

1. Using `insertAfter()`. [Picture#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmlta.png) [Picture#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvhJ3.png)
2. Using `insertAfter()` and removing `$.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);` in `_destroy()` function. [Picture#3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXyPf.png)
3. Using `appendChild()` and removing `$.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);` in `_destroy()` function. [Picture#4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT8AG.png)

Comments on tests:

1. It seems that some event triggering is happening. Due to `$.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);` call from `_destroy()` function, I have multiple `$.widget._destroy()` calls which leads to ~25% of usage. See [Picture#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvhJ3.png). Behavior of comboboxes as excepted.
2. It seems that removing `$.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);` from the code removes this event triggering. I don't see latency issues anymore. Behavior as excepted.
3. It seems that removing `$.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);` from the code removes this event triggering. I don't see latency issues anymore. Behavior not as excepted. Same behavior as stated in the explanation above.

Comment: I would be exceptionally surprised if creating 4 JQuery UI comboboxes on their own took a significant amount of time; how have you profiled the original code, and how are you profiling your changes to ensure your code gives a significant improvement in speed?

Comment: I haven't done a pro. performance test but this is very noticeable to the user who uses this portion of code. With original code takes ~2 seconds to open a window. With modified code takes less than a second to open a window. These measures are taken from my intuition.

Comment: Probably this `jFiddle` isn't enough to see the speed down as I have more "dependencies" in my project. By the way I have also tried to attach the input and following elements to directly the `div` wrapper but same behavior. Something is messing with the listeners perhaps. So all of them go to the last field.

Comment: Well after adding some rudimentary profiling (see http://jsfiddle.net/T2CdR/), it takes ~30ms for your version, and for the original version (I copy pasted from http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/a-jquery-ui-combobox-under-the-hood to http://jsfiddle.net/ZCxnV/) took ~35ms on average on my machine (a very high end machine, but still).

I would humbly suggest it is these other dependencies that might be causing the performance impact you're seeing; otherwise such a high performance impact would be a big issue.

Comment: @bloopletech I think I may have found the problem. Have a look at `$.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);` in the `_destroy()`. In the developer tools in Chromium I observe that:
1. Using `insertAfter` there's some event triggering happening which takes almost the same time as the program does.
2. Commenting `$.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);` makes almost no difference, to me, using `insertAfter` or `appendChild`. 
I'm updating the question!

Comment: After reading my update now I remember that using pure JS may mess with the event listeners... Same as issue `innerHTML` and `html()`.

Comment: @bloopletech Removing the `..destroy.call...` I avoid this huge difference but the thing is the using jQuery to create this combobox is still slightly noticeable for a developer user. If I don't use jQuery to attach the elements to their respective parts I have the mess with the listeners. I will go through the detailed example to see if I can do something about.